# retrieve the elements from a list-of-list data structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am running the following code segment

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
from skopt.space import Space
from skopt.sampler import Lhs
space = Space([(0., 1.), (0., 1.),(0.,1.)])
lhs = Lhs(lhs_type="centered", criterion=None)
theta_design = lhs.generate(space.dimensions, 200)
```

the resulting theta_design is a list with length `200`. Each list element is also a list with length `3`. Part of the result is shown as follows. So the theta_design is kind of a matrix with size `200*3`. My question is how to retrieve the elements along the first dimension  of this list-of-list structure. In other words, I want to retrive the first 100 elements from this matrix.

[image]

Comment: if `theta_design` is numpy array then use numpy's indexing `theta_design[:100, 0]` -> this gives you the first 100 hundred rows and takes the value of 1st element in each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are wanting to grab the first element of each of the first 100 lists, and save them to a list.
This can be done with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
first_element_of_each_list = [row[0] for row in theta_design[:100]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
first_col, second_col, third_col = zip(*theta_design[:100])
```